# Python: Hang Man

Tags: python, tkinter

I used a list for add the right letter in output, but if the word have a doble letter, the program    put the second letter in a wrong place.
My friend had replicated it on c++ and he have used the same algoritm(line 61-64) and it worked for him.
Can someone help me to fixed it?

This is the code:
'''

```
# coding=utf8

import tkinter as tk
import random as rm
from tkinter import messagebox

world_list = []
word = 'label'
attempts = 6
letter_used = ''

rdw = rm.choice(word)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Hang Man')
root.config(bg='#2C3333')
root.resizable(False, False)

lista = []
parola = ['-'] * len(word)
alive = True


def click():
    global attempts, alive

    if alive:
        e = en.get()
        x = False
        banned_symbols = '1234567890!"£$%&/()=?^\'[]@#_:;,.-<>'
        a.set('')

        if len(e) > 1:
            err['text'] = 'One letter for time!'
            err['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 13)
            err['bg'] = 'white'
            err['relief'] = 'ridge'
            err.grid(row= 6, column= 4)
            x = False
        elif e in banned_symbols:
            err['text'] = 'You have to insert only letters!'
            err['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 13)
            err['bg'] = 'white'
            err['relief'] = 'ridge'
            err.grid(row= 6, column= 4)
            x = False
        else:
            x = True

        if x:
            err['text'] = ''
            err['bg'] = '#2C3333'
            err['relief'] = tk.FLAT
            err.grid(row= 5, column= 5)

            sp = list(word)
            print(sp)


            letters = tk.Label(root, text= lista)
            if e in word:
                x = 0
                guess = ''
                for i in word:
                    if i == e:
                        parola[x] = e
                    else:
                        x+=1
                print(parola)

                
                out_lett['text'] = parola
                out_lett['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 20)
                out_lett['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 30)
                out_lett['fg'] = '#A5C9CA'
                out_lett.grid(row= 9, column= 4)



            else:
                if e not in lista:
                    attempts -= 1
                    f2['text'] = f'    Remaining attempts: {attempts}'
                    f2.grid(row= 1, column= 4)
                    print(attempts)
                    lista.append(e)
                    print(lista)
                    if len(lista) >= 14:
                        messagebox.showinfo(title= 'Word Used', message= lista)
                    if attempts == 0:
                        

                        alive = False
                else:
                    err['text'] = 'Letter already used'
                    err['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 13)
                    err['bg'] = 'white'
                    err['relief'] = 'ridge'
                    err.grid(row= 6, column= 4)

                letters = tk.Label(root, text= lista)
                letters['text'] = lista
                letters['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 12)
                letters['bg'] = '#99B9BA'
                letters.grid(row= 4, column= 5)
    else:
        err['text'] = 'You have lost'
        err['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 20)
        err['bg'] = 'white'
        err['relief'] = 'ridge'
        err.grid(row= 6, column= 4)

        mx = messagebox.askyesno(title= 'Game terminated', message= 'Do you want try again?')
        if mx == 'yes':
            alive = True
            attempts = 6
            err['text'] = ''
            err.grid(row= 6, column= 4)




def start_game():
    global err, en, a, out_lett

    out_lett = tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333')
    out_lett['text'] = parola
    out_lett['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 30)
    out_lett['fg'] = '#A5C9CA'
    out_lett.grid(row= 9, column= 4)

    l = 550 + (len(word) * 2)
    root.geometry(f'{l}x350')
    f1.destroy()
    f2['text'] = f'    Remaining attempts: {attempts}'
    f2.grid(row= 1, column= 4)
    b1.destroy()
    
    a = tk.StringVar()
    en = tk.Entry(root, textvariable= a)
    en.focus()
    en.grid(row= 3, column= 4, pady= 15, ipadx= 10)
    b2 = tk.Button(root, text= 'click', command= click)
    b2['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 10)
    b2['activebackground'] = '#395B64'
    b2['activeforeground'] = '#A5C9CA'
    b2.grid(row= 4, column= 4, ipadx= 8)
    
    tk.Label(root, text='', bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 2, column=5)
    space['text'] = f'Letter Used:'
    space['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 15)
    space['foreground'] = '#A5C9CA'
    space.grid(row= 3, column= 5)

    err = tk.Label(root, text='', bg= '#2C3333')
    err.grid(row= 5, column= 1)


    tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 5, column= 1)
    tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 6, column= 2)
    tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 7, column= 3)
    tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 9, column= 3)
    out_lett = tk.Label(root, bg= '#2C3333')
    out_lett.grid(row= 8, column= 4, ipady= 0)



f1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hang Man')
f1['foreground'] = '#A5C9CA'
f1['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 35, 'bold')
f1['bg'] = '#2C3333'
f1.grid(row= 1, column= 4)
f1['anchor'] = tk.N

f2 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Welcome to Hang Man, you have 6 attempts at win')
f2['underline'] = 30
f2['foreground'] = '#A5C9CA'
f2['justify'] = tk.CENTER
f2['font'] = ('Cormorant SC', 20)
f2['bg'] = '#2C3333'
f2.grid(row= 2, column= 4)

space = tk.Label(root, text= '', bg= '#2C3333')
space.grid(row= 3, column= 1)

b1 = tk.Button(root)
b1['text'] = 'Start'
b1['font'] = ('Roboto Condensed', 15)
b1['width'] = 10
b1['command'] = start_game
b1['activebackground'] = '#395B64'
b1['activeforeground'] = '#A5C9CA'
b1['relief'] = tk.GROOVE

b1.grid(row= 4, column=4)

tk.Label(root, text= '', bg= '#2C3333').grid(row= 5, column= 1)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-debugging service.  This might be a good time for you to practice your debug skills. The following  references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just missed the fact that you still need to increment your letter counter when you have a match.  Instead of:

```
for i in word:
    if i == e:
        parola[x] = e
    else:
        x+=1
```

You should have:

```
for i in word:
    if i == e:
        parola[x] = e
        x+=1        # Still need to do this when a letter matches
    else:
        x+=1
```

Or, even simpler:

```
for i in word:
    if i == e:
        parola[x] = e

    x+=1
```

When I tried that out with the clue word of "cacao", it worked.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Hangman$ python3 Hangman.py 
['c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'o']
Guess ['-', 'a', '-', 'a', '-']
['c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'o']
Guess ['c', 'a', 'c', 'a', '-']
['c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'o']
Guess ['c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'o']
```

Give that a try.